# Buying Organs in different Jurisdiction

Tags: jurisdiction

A [podcast](https://www.npr.org/2019/02/27/698563807/for-sale-by-owner-the-psychology-of-repugnant-transactions) indicated that it is illegal to buy \ sell a kidney in everywhere but [Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidney_trade_in_Iran) and was labelled a 'repugnant' transaction.  If an American who was critically in need of the organ went to Iran to receive a kidney, does American law provide for policing / enforcing law for an act that takes place in country XYZ?

Answer (score 2):

[42 USC 274e(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/274e) says

> It shall be unlawful for any person to knowingly acquire, receive, or
>   otherwise transfer any human organ for valuable consideration for use
>   in human transplantation if the transfer affects interstate commerce.
>   The preceding sentence does not apply with respect to human organ
>   paired donation.

And:

(3) The term “interstate commerce” has the meaning prescribed for it by [section 321(b) of title 21](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/21/321#b)

which says

> The term “interstate commerce” means (1) commerce between any
>   State or Territory and any place outside thereof, and (2) commerce
>   within the District of Columbia or within any other Territory not
>   organized with a legislative body.

Travel to Iran to obtain a kidney does not constitute an instance of interstate commerce, but the law is stated more broadly, as *affecting* interstate commerce (the reason for inserting that clause in the law is to relate it to a constitutional power of Congress). Which brings us to [Wickard v. Filburn](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/317/111/), where the court rules that growing wheat and feeding it to your own cattle *affects* interstate commerce.

The interpretation of the law has not yet been tested, to determine whether a US person traveling to another country and having an organ implanted for valuable consideration "affects" interstate commerce, so that they have violated US law.

Comment: interstate does not include Iran?  (is Iran a "state"?)

Comment: In US law, "State" means the 50 US states.

Comment: If Iran is not equal to state and it is interstate organ transport is forbidden: doesn't that imply no interstate market for organs?  It would seem there is  no interstate commerce to be affected?

Comment: The law says "affects interstate commerce", and does not require "transport". Hence Wickburn: no wheat was transported.

Comment: Good catch.  Let me try again: If organ-sales are forbidden: doesn't that imply no interstate organ-market exists? It would seem there is no interstate commerce to be affected?

Comment: See for example the Controlled Substances Act sect. 101, which clearly states that Congress has set out to make non-existent the interstate drug market, justifying ban on the intrastate market. There doesn't have to be an actual interstate market for Congress to invoke their Commerce Clause authority.